# C with assembly error: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-errors, clang, inline-assembly

I used this asm code in my c code , while compiling it gives me this error and i can't understand it

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    info_t info[] = {INFO_INIT};
    int fd = 2;

    asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t"
        "add $3, %0"
        : "=r" (fd)
        : "r" (fd));
```

and this is the console error

```
astssgery@astss-MacBook-Air codegram % gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu89 *.c -o hsh

main.c:16:5: error: extension used [-Werror,-Wlanguage-extension-token]
    asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t"
    ^
main.c:19:10: error: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier [-Werror,-Wasm-operand-widths]
                : "r" (fd));
                       ^
main.c:16:15: note: use constraint modifier "w"
    asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t"
              ^~
              %w1
main.c:18:11: error: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier [-Werror,-Wasm-operand-widths]
                : "=r" (fd)
```

Comment: Is your compiler targeting an ARM (AArch64) processor or an x86 processor? The inline assembly code you have appears to be for intel processors and I wonder if you are using a non-x86 tool chain on your Macbook Air.

Comment: Use `-Wno-language-extension-token` to disable the error for the `asm` extension.

Comment: its m1 macbook 64, and no im not using any tools @MichaelPetch

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/W71dWsnYf reproduces the same error messages with AArch64 clang trying to compile + assemble this x86 inline asm.  (`gcc` on MacOS is actually clang, unless you've installed real GCC.)

Comment: @Barmar I tried it and it gives error ``` main.c:16:23: error: invalid operand for instruction
    asm ("mov %1, %0\n\t"
                      ^
<inline asm>:2:6: note: instantiated into assembly here
        add $3, x8 ```

Comment: Barmar's suggestion does silence the `-pedantic` warning/error about `extension used [-Werror,-Wlanguage-extension-token]`. https://godbolt.org/z/xv8TevvK3  Of course that's not the only error; even without `-Werror` it won't assemble because `add $3, w0` isn't a valid AArch64 instruction.  Either compile this with an x86 cross-compiler, or write inline asm for AArch64.

Comment: *<source>:9:16: warning: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier [-Wasm-operand-widths]* is surprising to me but appears accurate.  Both GCC and clang expand `%1` and `%0` to 64-bit register names like `mov x8, x8`, even though the constraint was just `"r"(fd)` which is a 32-bit `int`.  For x86-64, GCC and clang do pick the 32-bit register EAX, not the full 64-bit RAX.  (https://godbolt.org/z/7hGfq5s9d has valid AArch64 inline asm so I could see how it compiles.)  So I guess you're supposed to use `%w1` and `%w0` to get the 32-bit reg name.

Comment: @tadman: your title edit is probably not all the OP is asking about.  That warning was the interesting part of the question for me, but the OP's actual problem is trying to compile x86 inline asm with an AArch64 (ARM) compiler.  And with warnings turned on that include `-Werror` and a warning for even using `asm()` at all since it's an extension to ISO C89, so even if they used x86 clang (which an M1 Mac definitely has, they should google how to build x86 binaries on M1 macs) they'd still get an error from using an ancient `-std=gnu89` with `-pedantic`.

Comment: @PeterCordes The intent was just to move the title from something super generic to at least slightly more focused on the problem. If it's shifted from that, worth another edit.

Comment: @tadman: It's focused on *a* problem now, but really a more accurate title is "error when trying to compile x86 inline asm with an AArch64 compiler, also with overly strict -pedantic clang warning settings".  The size-mismatch warning wouldn't happen if they were using an x86 compiler, although it still would if we instead change the asm to be valid AArch64 like in the last Godbolt link in my earlier comments.  Totally unclear what the OP wants to do, but presumably they're following an x86 inline asm tutorial so they actually want that, not AArch64 inline asm modifiers.

Comment: @tadman: TL:DR: this question is such a mess of so many things wrong at once that even after this edit, it wouldn't be a good place to write an answer about that warning message (which they've promoted to an error with `-Werror`).  If anything it's probably duplicate of of a question about how to build for x86-64 on AArch64 macOS, plus something about not using `-pedantic`, or I guess using `__asm__` instead of `asm` since that also silences the warning about tokens that are extensions (and would stop working with `-std=c11` instead of `gnu11`).

Comment: If you're trying to have constraints that are input/output, then I think doing: `asm("mov %1, %0\n\t" "add $3, %0" : "=r" (fd) : "r" (fd));` should be: `asm("add $3, %0" : "+r" (fd));`